# Cant make website public with Amazon Windows 2012 server and IIS

Tags: amazon-ec2, iis, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012

I cannot seem to access the domain I just created with IIS on my Amazon VPS. We run a Windows 2012 VPS with IIS installed as the server and I was wondering how I can get it to work publically on any computer? I did all the steps I was supposed to.. IE.. I created an instance made it accessible on ports 80 and 443, I logged in and installed IIS, I created a folder containing Default.htm and then I added the site. Next I enabled it, and edited hosts file adding the lines

```
127.0.0.1       smartleadtools.com
127.0.0.1       www.smartleadtools.com
```

so that I can access it like a webpage. Now when I go and access it within the VPS itself I get the page content. But when I go and try on another computer I get

```
This site can’t be reached

www.smartleadtools.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
```

Clearly that is not the case as you can see here

[As you can see here, domain is accessible from the remote VPS machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdKDb.png)

But from my actual local machine I cannot access that same page as you can see here this is the page I get instead

[Page I get instead of the page I get in the VPS machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxOms.png)

What can I do to fix this? How can I make my site public without a domain name. I want to host it purely with IIS how can users access that webpage?

Comment: I am just trying to host a page, I do not want to register any domains with HostGater or any other hosts. I want to host it myself.

Comment: Do I need to use our private IP, public IP? What should I do to make it public within IIS?

Comment: "How can I make my site public without a domain name?" - I don't know anything about IIS specifically, but if you don't have a domain name, then obviously you can't access it through its domain name. Have you tried using the public IP address instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General steps are

- Set up your server, install web server, configure for the domain you want to host, then test from the instance or perhaps another spot instance
- Allocate an elastic IP and associate it with your instance. If you don't do this the public IP will change every time you stop and start the server
- Ensure your security groups and routing allow access from the internet
- Insert a DNS A record that points at your elastic IP. You're doing this with a hosts file which is a good way to test things. The hosts file change needs to be on your local PC, not the AWS instance

You need to post more about your configuration and results of sensible tests like trying to curl it from the instance with the web server or a different spot instance.

Also, your user name "You will not get rid of me" is rather provocative, will likely annoy people, and will reduce the answers you get to your questions. It's also pointless, people here who ask reasonable questions get help. If you can change it I suggest you do.

Comment: I was blocked from the other sites 5 times. You would get irritated and run out of original names too.

Comment: For this one question all happened today.

Comment: Well, using a name like that is a good way to antagonize people. Suggest you alter your name and just act normally and you'll be welcome here.

Comment: Act normally? I asked a question, nobody answered, mods just deleted it and blocked accounts. Anyway, so which IP do I bind? I have to create an elastic IP address you said? Or use public/private?

Comment: I was able to get a page with the elastic IP

Comment: But I was still not able to resolve www.smartleadtools.com

Comment: I could only get the IIS Default page not the smartleadtools.com

Comment: What do I do next? @Tim

Comment: I also changed my name

Comment: Okay so the problem now is that I dont have smartleadtools pointed to the network... So how can I do that exactly?

Comment: Btw, I accepted your answer. It worked, although how do I add it so amazon can read it?

Comment: Domain names arent working...

Comment: Calm down and avoid repeated comments. This is a professional site, not a chat with technical support. Think about what you want to say, gather information including logs and configuration, and edit your question to provide information to help dianoisis. If you can resolve the page with the IP you then need to set up DNS, create an A record for the base domain (smartleadtools.com) and point it at your elastic IP. Create a cname that points the www subdomain at the main A record. New records are usually available instantly, but can take up to 24 hours to be accessible in some cases.

Comment: I see... is that done with IIS or Web server?

Comment: Also, I just replaced the default page with our own for now. So, I guess the last thing I need to know is how to access it via the domain name I set it to.. I dont understand how that is done.

Comment: I dont want to get another 3rd party domain however, I want to host directly from IIS

Comment: You'll need to register your domain with someone like GoDaddy, then edit the DNS records on the GoDaddy site. I don't want to be mean, but you're asking exceptionally basic questions that would be answered by a simple tutorial on web hosting. SF is for professional questions, not basics of getting a web site started. I'm happy to help, but I suspect this question will be closed when a moderator sees it. I suggest that you need to either need to learn the basics yourself, with a tutorial or something, or hire someone to help you.

Comment: I installed DNS and domain name tools from IIS you are saying those are useless right now?

Comment: I don't know what they are, I've worked with websites for two decades, but never with IIS. The DNS changes you need to do to make your website accessible via a domain name are typically done with your domain registrar. Technically you can run your own DNS server, but I advise that you use the DNS your registrar provides, as it's simpler and more reliable.

Comment: Well I do have a DNS tab, but microsoft made it hard to use. Ill check into it. Thank you for your time. I can access the site via IP now I just need to get DNS/Domain

Answer (score 0):

The DNS problem you're having is that you've modified HOSTS on the IIS server, but that does not actually register the domain to be accessed from anywhere but **on the actual server**.

After giving your EC2 instance an Elastic IP address, like @Tim says, you need to do the following:

1. Register the domain name with a service like GoDaddy, Route 53, etc.
2. Once you have the domain name registered, then you need to use a DNS service, like GoDaddy or Route 53 to assign the `smartleadtools.com` and `www.smartleadtools.com` DNS entries to the Elastic IP address you have assigned to the EC2 instance.

I know you say you want to avoid using third-party services, **but you cannot avoid it**. If you do not register the domain, then outside computers cannot reach your EC2 by the `www.smartleadtools.com` domain. Simply putting the domain on IIS does you no good.

---

There is one way to avoid registering your domain with a third-party service, and that is getting everyone that's going to access your server to modify the `hosts` file (like you did on the server) on their own computers. But that is not a realistic solution.

Comment: I did install the DNS tools with IIS, I was wondering if I could use that instead?

Comment: I cannot add any more pictures but I was wondering if I could just create a domain with the DNS Manager

Comment: @IgnatiusReborn 2.0 that still does not create a globally accessible domain name.

Comment: Well GoDaddy obviously creates domains. I would like to know how they did it.

Comment: There has to be a way to do it from IIS

Comment: GoDaddy is a globally recognized DNS registrar.

Comment: @IgnatiusReborn2.0 GoDaddy (and every other registrar) can create domains because they have a multi-million-dollar contract with ICANN. Do you want to negotiate a multi-million-dollar contract with ICANN? (I'm not sure of the exact details obviously)